# Silently uninstall software using its GUID

Tags: c#, uninstallstring

I want to uninstall my software that only prompt a UAC window and after that it doesn't show any UI.
i am using msiexec.exe to uninstall it. But how can i do it silently....

```
MsiExec.exe /x{Product Guid}
```

how it is possible in silent mode

Comment: what has this to do with C#/development?

Comment: my code is in c#, i know there is nothing to do with c# development

Comment: sorry but this is no question for SO - look in Server Fault (basically ask an administrator/IT guy - but personally I think the UAC is there for good reasons and you should not be able to silently uninstall it without administrator rights)

Comment: i dont want to bypass the UAC but after UAC i dont want to show any uninstallation wizard.

Comment: Or  can you suggest me that how can i design a uninstaller for my application. that only prompt for permission of uninstallation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
MsiExec.exe /x{Product Guid} /quiet
```

You can see all the supported options if you just type msiexec in the cmd.